# Unauthenticated user redirection for a custom membership system mvc5

Tags: security, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization

I am developing an erp system using mvc5. i have my own membership system built and user and his user permission is kept in a session variable once a user logged in. Authorization part is almost done i suppose. But for authentication now im trying to restrict access for unauthenticated users. I tried it like this

in my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

and on controllers i put [Authorize] attribute.

This works fine for unauthenticated users. They are redirected to login page. But this restricts the access of authenticated users as well.(This means neither unauthenticated nor authenticated user can access the controllers which has authorize attribute).

If i remove authorize attribute it gives me an error since there is no user to be assigned to session variable. This implies that without authorize attribute
unauthenticated user can access the controllers even-though the web.config has been modified.

I think this involves creating a custom attribute. But i don't know how to approach this. All help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a research i came up with the solution. 
I created a custom authorize attribute.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authroized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        // Now check the session:
        var myvar = httpContext.Session["User"];
        if (myvar == null)
        {
            // the session has expired
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And on my controllers instead of [authorize] i put [CustomAuthorize].

In web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```